# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED (_ssl.c:600) self-signed certificate

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm working on a local network :

1. PC A (windows 10, wamp): server
2. PC B (raspbian) : client

I'm trying to secure connection between the client and the server. What I have done :

1. Configure wamp on the server enabling ssl
2. Created a self-signed CA with openssl
3. Put the CA in my client at /usr/local/share/ca-certificates + update

Here's my code of my client

```
import ssl
import socket
import pprint

#custom context
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL
context.check_hostname = True
#self-signed certificate location
context.load_verify_locations("/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/server.pem")

#TER is defined in /etc/hosts
conn = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET), server_hostname="TER")
conn.connect(("TER", 443))

#fetch cert
cert = conn.getpeercert()
pprint.pprint(cert)
```

But this error occurs :

[SSLError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKbd1.png)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. By the way, I'm total novice !
Thanks for your help !

Comment: You are using the server certificate as a "valid issuer of certs" and not the actual issuer root CA cert, there for the server certificate won't validate.